# Subset character vector by pattern

Tags: r, vector, unique

I have a character vector made up of filenames like:

```
vector <- c("LR1_0001_a", "LR1_0002_b", "LR02_0001_b", "LR02_0002_x", "LR3_001_c")
```

My goal is to subset this vector based on pattern matching the first x number of characters (dynamically), up to the first "_". The outputs would look something like this:

```
solution1 <- c("LR1_0001_a", "LR1_0002_b")
solution2 <- c("LR02_0001_b", "LR02_0002_b")
solution3 <- c("LR3_001_c")
```

I have experimented with mixtures of `unique` and `grep` but have not had any luck so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove everything after underscore `"_"` and `split` the vector.

```
output <- split(vector, sub('_.*', '', vector))
output

#$LR02
#[1] "LR02_0001_b" "LR02_0002_x"

#$LR1
#[1] "LR1_0001_a" "LR1_0002_b"

#$LR3
#[1] "LR3_001_c"
```

This returns a list of vectors, which is usually a better way to manage data instead of creating number of objects in global environment. However, if you want them as separate vectors we can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(output, .GlobalEnv)
```

This will create vectors with the name `LR02`, `LR1` and `LR3` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (coerce vector to data.frame):

```
# Split vector into list (as in ronak's answer): 

vect_list <- split(vect, sub("_.*", "", vect)) 

# Pad each vector in the list to be the same length as the longest vector: 

padded_vect_list <- lapply(vect_list, 
                           function(x){length(x) = max(lengths(vect_list)); return(x)})

# Coerce the list of vectors into a dataframe: 

df <- data.frame(do.call("cbind", padded_vect_list))
```

Data:

```
vect <- c("LR1_0001_a", "LR1_0002_b", "LR02_0001_b", "LR02_0002_x", "LR3_001_c")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `trimws`

```
out <- split(vector, trimws(vector, whitespace = "_[a-z]+"))
```

and then use `list2env`

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```